# Spartacus 4.0.0 - Property 'BEFORE' does not exist on type 'OutletPosition'

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am trying to develop a page in Spartacus 4.0.0 and link it with SAP Hybris 1905 B2B site. i want to modify the header section of spartacus using Outlets and Outlet position. for some reason i get below error while adding "cxOutletPos".

```
Error: src/app/core/custom-components/custom-header/custom-header.component.html:1:67 - error TS2339: Property 'BEFORE' does not exist on type 'OutletPosition'.

<ng-template cxOutletRef="SiteLogo" [cxOutletPos]="outletPosition.BEFORE" let-model>
```

Appreciate if someone can help me out here.

Comment: have you tried just lower case before?

[cxOutletPos]="before"

Comment: Tried [cxOutletPos]="before" too, same error.

Comment: Did you have a correct import in your *.ts file? import {OutletPosition} from '@spartacus/storefront';

Answer (score 0):

`SiteLogo` is not a valid outlet. You can see the list of all the available outlets at the documentation link below.

https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/outlets/#software-driven-outlet-references

Comment: SiteLogo as outlet ref and before as outlet position works fine in Spartacus 3.4. Wondering anything different i have to do for 4.0

Comment: you could also try `cxOutletRef="SiteLogoComponent"` to see if works?